# Select max date for each register, null if does not exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these tables: Employee (id, name, number), Configuration (id, years, licence_days), Periods (id, start_date, end_date, configuration_id, employee_id, period_type):

```
Employee table:
id   name  number
---- ----- -------  
1    Bob    355 
2    John   467 
3    Maria  568 
4    Josh   871 

configuration table:
id   years licence_days 
---- ----- ------------  
1    1     8
2    3     16 
3    5     24 

Periods table:
id   start_date   end_date   configuration_id   employee_id    period_type
---- ----------   -------    ----------------   -----------   -----------
1    2021-05-23   2021-05-31    1                  1          vaccation
2    2021-05-24   2021-06-01    1                  2          vaccation
3    2021-03-01   2021-03-17    2                  2          vaccation
4    2021-05-05   2021-05-21    2                  2          vaccation
5    2021-01-01   2021-01-17    2                  4          vaccation
```

I want this result:

```
Result:
employee_id   years   licence_days   max(end_date)
1             1       8              2021-05-31
1             3       16             null
1             5       24             null
2             1       8              2021-06-01
2             3       16             2021-05-21
2             5       24             null
3             1       8              null
3             3       16             null
3             5       24             null 
4             1       8              null
4             3       16             2021-01-17
4             5       24             null
```

i.e., I want to select all Employees with all configuration, and for each one of that, the max end_date of the "vaccation" type (or null if it does not exists).

How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle supports cross joins, right? So may be something like that?

```sql
SELECT e.employee_id, c.years, c.licence_days, max(p.end_date)
FROM Employee e
  CROSS JOIN configuration c
  LEFT JOIN Periods p
    ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id
    AND c.configuration_id = p.configuration_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id, c.years, c.licence_days
ORDER BY e.employee_id, c.years
```

Answer (score 1):

@umberto-petrov chooses wisely with the ANSI `CROSS JOIN` syntax for a cartesian join. However, in the very weak probability that your requires output of configurations even where there is no employees, you can go with something like :

**EDIT:** Filtering the `Periods` join with 'vaccation' as asked in the comments.
If you have to filter for some employee ids, change `ON 1 = 1` by `ON Employee.id IN (id1, id2, ...)`. It still keeps every configurations but only takes employees that match the ids.

```sql
SELECT Employee.employee_id, 
       Configuration.years,
       Configuration.licence_days,
       MAX(Configuration.end_date) max_end_date
  FROM Configuration LEFT JOIN Employee ON 1 = 1
                     LEFT JOIN Periods ON Periods.configuration_id = Configuration.id 
                                      AND Periods.employee_id = Employee.id  
                                      AND Periods.period_type = 'vaccation'
 GROUP BY Employee.employee_id, 
          Configuration.years,
          Configuration.licence_days
 ORDER BY Employee.employee_id, 
          Configuration.years,
          Configuration.licence_days
```

We start from *configuration* to take every records from this one at least, then made a `LEFT CARTESIAN JOIN` with *Employee* and finally a full `LET JOIN` on *Periods* for both. That way , if there is no employees, this will output *configuration_id* and *NULL*  for *years*, *licence_days* and max *end_date*.

Comment: I added a very important information on that. My "where' clause has to be period-type = vaccation, because i have another period types that does not matter for me

Comment: And sometimes I have to be able to filter by employee id.

Comment: @aseolin Edit done. I suggest you to mark umberto-petrov's answer as accepted as it was the first and should have fit your initial needs (the "no employees" case would had been then fairly unexpected).